# how to writ regex and how making more one group in java?

Tags: java, regex

Please help me! I am writing a program in Java using Regex. I have many structures for the sentence.

Given sentence - "book 'learning java' for doctor Ahmed Mohamed" or "The best title: learning java for Ahmed Mohamed ", and so on.

that means:

> (book) may be [the book or text: or (text)].
>
> (for doctor ) may be [ for author or for or by or for doctor].

the regex is:

```
"(?<=(book| the book| \\ (\\)|\\:)) .*? (?=(for doctor| for| for author))"
```

the output:

I want to extract any words after (book) and before (for doctor ) and named it Title. And extract any words after (for doctor ) and named it Author.

```
String inputtext =  "book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed";
                                                 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=(book| the book| \\ (\\)|\\:)) .*? (?=(for doctor| for| for author))");
    
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputtext);
    
    if (m.matches()) {
        String author = m.group(1).trim();
        String bookTitle = m.group(2).trim();
        
        System.out.println("Title is : " + author);
        System.out.println("Author is : " + bookTitle);
```

This program gives me error at running and i would to be shore from Regex.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing a `)`. `\\)` is an escaped `)`, so `(\\)|\\:)` is surrounded by brackets, and `(book| the book| \\ (\\)|\\:))` is also, but then `(?<=` doesn't have a closing bracket.
2. I'm pretty sure you can't use look-around on `Matcher::matches()` because it tries to match the whole string, so look-around will look before the start of the string and after the end of the string. Using `Matcher::find()` works better.
3. Everything in brackets are groups (except look-around and non-capturing groups), so group 1 is `(book| the book| \\ (\\)|\\:))` and group 2 is `(\\)|\\:)`
4. `(book| the book| \\ (\\)|\\:))` (and `for doctor|...`) doesn't really need to be in brackets as the look-around brackets are sufficient.
5. It seems you have too many spaces in your regex (they are part of the regex, so they need to be matched).
6. If you use look-ahead on the `for doctor|for|for author` part, you won't be able to capture the author.
7. You don't need look-around at all.

**Which brings us to:**

```
String inputtext =  "book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(book|\\)|\\:) (.*) for( doctor| author|) (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputtext);
if (m.find()) {
    String title = m.group(2).trim();
    String author = m.group(4).trim();
    System.out.println("Title is : " + title);
    System.out.println("Author is : " + author);
}
```

**If you do want to use matches:**

```
String inputtext =  "book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:book|the book|(?:\\(.*?\\))|.*?\\:) (.*) for(?: doctor| author|) (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputtext);
if (m.matches()) {
    String title = m.group(1).trim();
    String author = m.group(2).trim();

    System.out.println("Title is : " + title);
    System.out.println("Author is : " + author);
}
```

The `?:` is simply a non-capturing group, without them the match will be the same, but you'll have to use `group(3)` and `group(5)` instead of `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: `(?>pattern)` is not simply non-capturing group. It also has *possessive behaviour*, in other words, it disallow backtracking. Is it really necessary to prevent backtracking?

Comment: `should be approached with caution` Are you completely sure it should be used (or should not be used)?

Comment: @nhahtdh Edited. Removed any mention of `?>`.

Comment: Actually, `(?:pattern)` is the correct one for non-capturing group. `(?>pattern)` disable backtracking and can be used for optimization, I am just not sure whether it applies here or not.

Comment: @ShimaaMohamed Remember to [upvote and/or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) this answer if you found it helpful.